# Export & Save PDF for Each Record

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am using the following code to export a reportviewer report to PDF:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;

byte[] bytes = rptvInvoice.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, 
                  out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

string strFilePath = @"C:\Temp\";
string strFileName = "Blah.PDF";
string filename = Path.Combine(strFilePath, strFileName);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
     fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

It works great but, is there a way to export each RECORD of data as opposed to the entire report?  Each record can span 1-N pages and I want to save each record of data (spanning 1-N pages) in separate PDF files instead of one big PDF that contains all the records in one report.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

FYI, I think I am using reportviewer 2005 and am not sure how easy it would be to migrate all the other reports to a newer version.

Comment: I believe you would need to create a new report which contains the information related to a single record. You would then generate a PDF for each record.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I have to do since I do not think there is a way for the reportviewer component to tell how many pages each record takes up in the full report in order to break it up into multiple PDFs.  Thanks

Comment: If you are using Local Processing Mode you could simply only provide the report with one record of data at a time, then use this same method of exporting.